# c# tripleDESCrypto saved and retrieved from sql not working

Tags: c#, sql, tripledes

hey there, so in a msSQL database that i'm saving and retrieving from using stored procedures. i'm trying to encrypt some data in the c# windows form before being placed, and then of course decrypting it when i pull it back. all the encryption is being handled on the c# side. i'm using the sample code for encryption and decryption verbatim from [microsoft's tripleDESCryptoService Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tripledescryptoserviceprovider.aspx) (the memory version, 2nd example).  The values get encrypted and sent to the database, but when retrieving it i get a "bad data" error.
a sample of the encryption call is...

```
TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tDESalg = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] tempByte = new byte[100];
tempByte = encrypt(txt_Last_Name.Text, tDESalg.Key, tDESalg.IV);
txt_Last_Name.Text = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(tempByte);
```

the txt_Last_Name is then sent to the database, and i can see that there is something in the database. in the database, last name is of type varchar(20)

sample of the decryption call is...

```
TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tDESalg = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
string lastName = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("Last Name"));
if (isEncrypted)
{
     byte[] toDecrypt = new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(lastName);
     lastName = decrypt(toDecrypt, tDESalg.Key, tDESalg.IV);                    
}
txt_Last_Name.Text = lastName;
```

it bombs in the decryption function at: "csDecrypt.Read(fromEncrypt, 0, fromEncrypt.Length);"  and i don't understand why. i'm not sure if it's not getting stored in the database correctly, or my conversions aren't right.

if it means anything, the "Data" coming into the decrypt function is of size 16 and contains non-zero values, but the "byte[] fromEncrypt" is an array of size 16 containing all zeros.

thanks for any help!

Comment: You should not process tempByte as a Unicode string, not even as a string.

Comment: TripleDES is consider as weak. You should consider using AES instead :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Okay, we've got to the bottom of it... although the ASCII issue would have bitten too.

Every time you create a new `TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider` and ask it for a key/IV, it will generate a new one. You need to store that securely somewhere, as it's required to decrypt the data. Otherwise you don't have any "secret" so it's not really encryption...

---

This is a terrible idea:

```
txt_Last_Name.Text = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(tempByte);
```

You've got arbitrary binary data in `tempByte`. *Don't* assume it's valid ASCII text. That's almost certainly where you're losing data.

Use [`Convert.ToBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx) and [`Convert.FromBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx) to safely encode opaque binary data as text.

Additionally, this is a bad idea:

```
byte[] tempByte = new byte[100];
tempByte = encrypt(txt_Last_Name.Text, tDESalg.Key, tDESalg.IV);
```

What's the point of creating a byte array if you're then going to ignore it? Use

```
byte[] tempByte = encrypt(txt_Last_Name.Text, tDESalg.Key, tDESalg.IV);
```

instead. Oh, and try to follow .NET naming conventions :)

Having said all of this, if your encryption is always returning a byte array of 16 zeroes, that's a pretty sure sign that your `encrypt` method is broken. We can't really help there until you post the code for that method.

Finally, if your column is of type `varchar(20)` you should be aware that that may very well not hold all the data you need it to... particularly if you're going to include a salt. Base64 will increase the size of the data somewhat, and encryption may do so too. As mentioned in another answer, storing this as binary *in the database* would be more sensible in many ways.

(Note: even if you *did* want to use that code, I'd write it as `txt_Last_Name.Text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(tempByte);`. Using directives are your friend, and [`ASCII`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.ascii.aspx) is a property of `Encoding`, not `ASCIIEncoding`.)

Comment: Googling this story of conversion of byte[] to chars, it is surprising the number of wrong solutions based upon the use of ASCIIEncoding...

Comment: @pascal: The use of *any* normal Encoding is a problem here... but it's usually ASCII or UTF-8.

Comment: i provided the encryption method via a link, it's on microsoft's tripleDES...Provider class page in msdn.  tempByte was just for a proof of concept.  i changed that, got rid of creating the byte array and then ignoring it, am using the convert.to and from for the base 64. it still fails. guess i'm going to have to try the binary type in sql...

Comment: @dave: Personally I don't trust that MSDN code hugely to start with, as it will lose data for non-ASCII strings, and doesn't use `using` statements for the streams. But I'd be surprised if it really returned byte arrays just with zeroes in. One thing: try to do all of this without using SQL server *at all* to start with. Just encrypt and then decrypt without transferring the data anywhere. Do that in a console app, just to test it.

Comment: yes, i have done that already to make sure it does work, it does.

Comment: @dave: Okay, was that with the base64 version? If so, you can isolate the problem to a failure to store and retrieve text in the database, and leave the encryption side out of it. How long are the base64 strings?

Comment: sorry bout the delay, went to lunch. ok. testing it in a console app, exactly as it is in the example works. putting it into a windows form(without database) fails. the windows form is 3 text boxes, input, encrypted, decrypted and two buttons to encrypt and decrypt. i'm using the convert.to/frombase64string

Comment: @dave: I think your testing must be flawed then. If you can post the minimal console and WinForms apps, we'll see *how* they're flawed...

Comment: i found that if i move the "TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tDESalg = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();" out of each button click, in the winform test, then it worked...odd? but still trying to get it to actually work in the program it needs to be in...

Comment: @dave k: Do you mean you were trying to decrypt using a different key than the one you encrypted with? Of *course* that will fail! I should have spotted that before. You need to be consistent in your keys... will edit my answer.

Comment: shoot! um... do i need to store the value for both the Key and IV?

Comment: @dave: Yes. Have a look at the docs for SymmetricAlgorithm.IV: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.iv.aspx

Comment: so...hypotheically speaking...if i were to store the Key and IV in a sql database, the best choice would be a binary(max) type, since it looks like they are of type byte[]? and then to retrieve it what do i use? byte[] key = dr.GetSqlBytes(dr.GetOrdinal("key"));

Comment: @dave: Possibly. Or you could base64-encoded them both and use text fields, if you find those simpler to work with. It would be a bad idea to do so in general though - pretty much like writing down your password on a post-it note next to the laptop.

Comment: i keep my post-it notes under the laptop, not as visible. j/k :P  I don't have confirmation that this all works yet, will take me a bit to get it all going, but i'm marking yours as the answer, THANKS for ALL the help! on my first job out of college and sometimes i feel like all i learned was theory and very little actual know-how.

Answer (score 0):

Just [reading the doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)... you should convert your byte[] to a String using `Convert.ToBase64String()`.

Comment: ... and Jon Skeet beating me by 32s, gives the counterpart: `Convert.FromBase64String`.

Comment: yea, tried that method of conversion, still doesn't work...thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Either Convert.ToBase64String(), as pascal recommended above, or store the data as binary in your database instead of text (the preferred solution, since it would use less space). In SQL Server, there is a VARBINARY(MAX) data type for this very purpose.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that Jon's answer already did suggest storing as binary.